# What Happened to The Latex Symbols In the Libreoffice-Texmaths Equation Editor?

Tags: apt, package-management, libreoffice, latex

I recently purged Libreoffice because it was buggy.

I then reinstalled the latest version from `apt` and now it's missing the symbols above the equation editor.

Here is the current Texmaths equation editor:
[image: Texmaths Equation Editor]

There used to be shortcuts for latex including `frac{}{}` and various set theory operations, as well as the binomial distribution on the top of the window.

What happened to them and how do I get them back? I just figured that they were in some package and installed all packages useing `sudo apt install libreoffice*`, but this didn't help after I refreshed the program.

**EDIT 0:** I'm using Kubuntu 19.04

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libreoffice-texmaths libreoffice-writer texlive
libreoffice-texmaths:
  Installed: 0.43-2
  Candidate: 0.43-2
  Version table:
 *** 0.43-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libreoffice-writer:
  Installed: 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
texlive:
  Installed: 2018.20190227-1
  Candidate: 2018.20190227-1
  Version table:
 *** 2018.20190227-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed TeXMaths addon? What is the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-texmaths libreoffice-writer texlive`?

Comment: @N0rbert Kubuntu 19.04 and I posted the results in the edit I made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove packaged TexMaths 0.43-2 and install newest instead with the steps below:

1. Remove the `libreoffice-texmaths` package

   ```
    sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-texmaths
   ```
2. Remove configuration folder

   ```
    rm -rf ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/TexMaths
   ```
3. Download latest version from [TexMaths site](http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/), save *TexMaths-0.46.1.oxt* file.
4. Open downloaded *TexMaths-0.46.1.oxt* file in LibreOffice and confirm its installation.
5. Restart LibreOffice Writer, click [image: pi] to add new equation:

   > [image: TexMaths]

---

Note: packaged version do not have buttons in all Ubuntu releases, so I reported [bug 1828433](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice-texmaths/+bug/1828433).

Comment: Wow! Worked with no problems. Great solution. I didn't know that it wasn't added to the new release. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rename|Delete **~/.config/libreoffice/Number/user/registrymodifications.xcu** to reset LibreOffice Settings, save Keyboardsettings beforehand through the Menu.
Had a bit of Trouble with Office myself lately hahaa.